# выбрать корректную ветку для push

Tags: git, git-push

работаю над проектом на github, в самом проекте есть 2 ветки, бета и альфа, обычно работал в ветке альфа `alpha-branch` если я проверяю в `git git branch` то отображается только 1 ветка `alpha-branch`. сейчас возникла ситуация что нужно пролить в бету, но в списке branch только альфа. как можно запушить в таком случае на `beta-branch`?

после комментария проверил `git branch -r`, и правда отображается ряд удаленных веток..подскажите как запушить на нее в таком случае?

Comment: если я создам в проекте на локальном репозиторие ветку `beta-branch` и сделаю пуш, это будет правльно?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `git branch -r` — это показ веток во всех подключенных к вашему локальному удалённых репозиториев. изменить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexander barakin вы правы, при вводе команды `git branch -r` отображаются все удаленные ветки. чтобы запушить на нее нужно сделать подобную операцию - git push https://github.comsomething/project.git beta-branch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

команда (показан и примерный её вывод)

```
$ git branch -r
origin/ветка1
origin/ветка2
repo2/ветка3
repo3/ветка4
```

покажет все ветки всех подключенных к вашему локальному репозиторию удалённых репозиториев.

репозитории фигурируют под теми (произвольными) именами, под которыми они подключены. в данном случае: `origin`, `repo2` и `repo3`.

имя `origin` — по умолчанию присваивается удалённому репозиторию, например, при выполнении `git clone`.

в принципе, чтобы отправить изменения из текущей ветки в любую из веток любого из подключенных репозиториев, можно выполнить:

```
$ git push имя-репозитория имя-ветки
```

для приведённого выше примера отправить изменения в, например, `origin/ветка2`, можно так:

```
$ git push origin ветка2
```

но отправить изменения из *произвольной* локальной ветки в *произвольную* удалённую, скорее всего, не выйдет и вы можете получить ошибку вида:

> error: src refspec ветка2 does not match any

это говорит о том, что надо явно указать *источник*. это может быть имя локальной ветки, хэш конкретного коммита или метка (в том числе «специальная» — `HEAD`, которая указывает на текущий коммит, куда переключена ваша рабочая копия репозитория). примерно так:

```
$ git push имя-репозитория источник:ветка
```

но и это ещё не «победа». скорее всего, вы можете получить в ответ ошибку вида:

> To url-репозитория
>    ! [rejected]        источник -> ветка (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'url-репозитория'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
>   hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

это значит что ваш текущий коммит невозможно связать цепочкой коммитов с коммитом, на который указывает удалённая ветка (напомню, что ветка в *git* — это лишь «плавающий» указатель на коммит).

и действовать вам надо было несколько иначе.

например, так:

1. создать локальную ветку, основанную на удалённой, и переключиться на неё:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b ветка2 origin/ветка2
   ```
2. внести необходимые изменения, сделать необходимые коммиты.
3. отправить эти изменения в удалённый репозиторий:

   ```
   $ git push
   ```

Comment: большое спасибо за столь развернутый ответ)